# Deleting node in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

Most of code works but when I try to delete last element of my list and I print it I see in its place some garbage data, what I'm doing wrong here? Could somebody point my mistake?

```
void DeleteClient2(struct client *temp,struct client **head)
{   struct client *prev=*head;
    struct client *current = *head;
    struct item *currentitem = (*head)->item_data,*save;
    if(temp== *head)
    {
        while(currentitem != NULL)
        {
            save = currentitem;
            currentitem = currentitem ->next;
            free(save);
        }
        free(temp);
        temp->item_data = NULL;
        (*head) = (*head)->next;
    }
    else
    if(temp->next == NULL)
    {
        while(currentitem != NULL)
        {
            save = currentitem;
            currentitem = currentitem ->next;
            free(save);
        }
        temp->item_data = NULL;
        free(temp);
    }
    else
    if(temp != *head && temp->next != NULL)
    {
        while(prev->next != temp)
        {
            prev=prev->next;
        }
        prev->next = temp->next;
        while(currentitem != NULL)
        {
            save = currentitem;
            currentitem = currentitem ->next;
            free(save);
        }
        temp->item_data = NULL;
        free(temp);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: first indent your code correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void DeleteClient2(struct client *temp,struct client **head)
{   struct client *prev=*head;
    struct client *current = *head;
    struct item *currentitem = (*head)->item_data,*save;
    if(temp== *head) \\ if head is the node to be deleted
    {
        while(currentitem != NULL)
        {
            save = currentitem;
           *head = currentitem->next;
          \\  currentitem = currentitem ->next;
            free(save);
        }

    }
    else
    if(temp->next == NULL) \\ if the node to be deleted is last node then
    {
    while(currentitem->next != NULL)
        {
           *prev = currentitem;
            currentitem = currentitem ->next;

        }
        prev->next = NULL;
        free(currentitem);
}
else
if(temp != *head && temp->next != NULL)\\ node to be deleted is between head and last node
{while(prev->next != temp)
{   currentitem = *prev;
    prev=prev->next;
}
currentitem->next = temp->next;
free(temp);
\\while(currentitem != NULL)
    \\    {
    \\        save = currentitem;
    \\        currentitem = currentitem ->next;
    \\\        free(save);
    \\    }
      \\  temp->item_data = NULL;
     \\   free(temp);
     \\   temp=temp->next;
}
}
```

Comment: there may some mistake in my code but you can try this idea(the changes i have made

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
    free(temp);
    temp=temp->next;  // temp->next is invalid
```

Is undefined behaviour, Once you free a node you can't access it, doing so is illegal.

Comment: Than how should I link previous node and next node ?

Comment: @user3209183 keep Save previous address

Answer (score 0):

Here you check that *head == temp and if yes, you free temp i.e *head cause they equal, you just verified it, and than you say (*head) = (*head)->next; which set *head to garbage most probably

```
if(temp== *head)
{
    while(currentitem != NULL)
    {
        save = currentitem;
        currentitem = currentitem ->next;
        free(save);
    }
    free(temp);
    temp->item_data = NULL;
    (*head) = (*head)->next;
}
```

Same mess is here

```
    temp->item_data = NULL;
    free(temp);
    temp=temp->next;
```